# Modify input arguments of inherited class before initializing parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, input

I've been creating a geometry module. I have defined GeoTuple, Vector(GeoTuple), Normal(Vector). Because a normal must have a magnitude of 1, I need to take the input arguments and modify them before initiating Vector, see code below:

```
class GeoTuple(tuple, object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        try:
            if len(data) != 3:
                raise ValueError("Vector must have 3 members only")
            _floats = tuple(float(item) for item in data)
            super(GeoTuple, self).__init__(_floats)
        finally:
            pass

    def __add__(self, b):
        raise NameError("Concatenation has been disabled for GeoTuple")

    def __mul__(self, b):
        raise NameError("Shallow Copeis has been disabled for GeoTuple")


class Vector(GeoTuple, object):
    def __init__(self,point):
        super(Vector, self).__init__(point)


    @property
    def x(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self[1]

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self[2]

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        _x, _y, _z = self
        return sqrt(_x**2 + _y**2 + _z**2)


    def __add__(self, b):
        _p = (self.x + b.x, self.y + b.y, self.z + b.z)
        return Vector(_p)


    def __sub__(self, b):
        _p = (self.x - b.x, self.y - b.y, self.z - b.z)
        return Vector(_p)


    def __mul__(self, b):
        if isinstance(b, self.__class__):
            _s = self.x*b.x + self.y*b.y + self.z*b.z
            result = _s
        else:
            _s = float(b)
            _p = (self.x*_s, self.y*_s, self.z*_s)
            result = Vector(_p)
        return result


    def __abs__(self):
        return Vector((abs(self.x),abs(self.y),abs(self.z)))


    def __neg__(self):
        return Vector((-self.x, -self.y, -self.z))


    def cross(self, b):
        _p = [self.y*b.z - self.z*b.y, self.z*b.x - self.x*b.z, 
            self.x*b.y - self.y*b.x]
        return Vector(_p)


    def __xor__(self, b):
        return self.cross(b)


class Normal(Vector, object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        _x, _y, _z = data
        _mag = sqrt(_x**2 + _y**2 + _z**2)
        _p = [_x/_mag, _y/_mag, _z/_mag]
        super(Vector, self).__init__(_p)
```

Problem is, if I call:

```
n1 = Normal([1,3,8])
n1
```

it returns:

```
(1,3,8)
```

not

```
(0.11624763874381928, 0.34874291623145787, 0.9299811099505543)
```

---

### EDIT 1

I changed parameter name from point to data in normal (this was just a copy paste error). It is essential that GeoTuple remains immutable so it sounds like **new** would be the way to implement that? Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: In Normal's `__init__`, you passed an argument `point` but you tried to make use of a variable called `data` that doesn't exist.  Are you sure you're pasting the actual code you're running?

Comment: I changed parameter name from point to data in normal (this was just a copy paste error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing `__init__` from Normal and adding `__new__`, I was able to achieve what I was hoping.

```
class Normal(Vector, object):

    def __new__(self, data):
        _x, _y, _z = data
        _mag = sqrt(_x**2 + _y**2 + _z**2)
        _p = [_x/_mag, _y/_mag, _z/_mag]
        return Vector.__new__(self,_p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable and hence trying to change it in `__init__` is a tad late. Either you overwrite `__new__` or change your base class to list which is mutable.

This works:

```
class GeoTuple(list, object): #list not tuple

....

class Normal(Vector, object):
    def __init__(self, point):
        _x, _y, _z = point #same name as param
        _mag = (_x**2 + _y**2 + _z**2)**.5
        _p = [_x/_mag, _y/_mag, _z/_mag]
        super(Normal, self).__init__(_p) #right class name

n1 = Normal([1,3,8])
print n1
```

And the output is:

```
[0.11624763874381928, 0.34874291623145787, 0.9299811099505543]
```

Comment: It is essential that GeoTuple remains immutable so it sounds like __new__ would be the way to implement that? Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: I gather from your answer, that you already figured out the trick. Nicely done.

Answer (score -1):

The actual choice between underlying datastructures (tuple, list or something else) depends on how these objects will be used. If you may go with an immutable data, you may use `tuple` and override `__new__()` method as user @hansonap suggested. If you need modify data (likely) and be able to extend the number of stored entities in a single Point (unlikely) you may change `tuple` to `list`. But if you need to have a *lot* of `Point`s then you may consider [`array`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) as an underlying data storage etc. Also if you need a lot of math in your program, you may take a look at [`NumPy`](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: I fixed that in my code above. It was a copy paste error on my part. Unrelated to the issue at hand however.